# Две активные вкладки TabControl или как отменить смену вкладки?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Имеется `TabControl` с 3-мя вкладками `TabItem`. Для каждой вкладки есть своя `VM`. Все это дело хранится в коллекции `ObservableCollection<AbstractVM> TabItemsVM`.

```
  <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding TabItemsVM}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTabVM}"
              TabStripPlacement="Top"> 
        <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}"/>
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"/>                                       
            </Style>
        </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </TabControl>
```

[image: работает]

При выборе другой вкладки из кода путем присвоения `SelectedTabVM` `TabItemsVM[0]`. Код ниже:

```
_selectedTabVM = TabItemsVM[0]; //присваиваю именно приватному полю,
                                //т.к. в публичном, в сеттере хранится некая логика проверки.
                                //в то время как я хочу изменить вкладку без проверки
//Вызываю PropertyChanged("SelectedTabVM");
```

вкладка меняется, пока все нормально:

реализация `SelectedTabVM`:

```
private Abstract VM _selectedTabVM;
public AbstractVM SelectedTabVM
    {
        get { return _selectedTabVM; }
        set
        {
            if (modeChangeExecute())
            {
                _selectedTabVM = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedTabVM");
            }                 
        }
    }
```

[image: работает]

Но при переключении вкладки уже через интерфейс получается вот такая картина:

[image: не работает]

т.е. у двух вкладок свойство `IsSelected` уставлено в `True`.
 В чем может быть дело? Почему у той вкладки на которую я перешел из кода свойство `IsSelected` не снимается

**UPD**
Нашел не совсем похожую проблему на англоязычном stackoverflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929646/how-to-programmaticaly-select-a-tabitem-in-wpf-tabcontrol

здесь похоже на сам баг контрола `TabControl` в `WPF`

Comment: Покажите реализацию свойства SelectedTabVM

Comment: @PavelMayorov обновил

Comment: Когда возникает ситуация с двумя активными вкладками - `modeChangeExecute()` возвращает true или false?

Comment: там вылезает диалоговое окно, `да или нет`. В обоих случаях вне зависимости от результата получаются две активные вкладки.

Comment: @S.Kost: А вот это и есть проблема. Уберите диалоговое окно из сеттера, у вас получается рекурсия: значение свойства ещё не поменялось, а уже выполнилась следующая итерация event loop'а. Как вы думаете, какое должно быть с точки зрения WPF значение selected item на время работы вашего диалогового окна?

Comment: @VladD, Да, без диалогового окна все работает. Но как иметь возможность отменить изменение вкладки?

Comment: @S.Kost: Должно быть можно, почему нет? Сейчас набросаю пример.

Comment: @S.Kost: Окей, это было дольше, чем предполагалось :) Пример готов и работает. Сейчас напишу ответ.

Comment: @VladD, буду рад увидеть долгожданное решение!)

Comment: @S.Kost: Готово!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема заключается в том, что вы блокируете сеттер диалогом. На время показа диалога свойство ж должно иметь какое-то значение, так что система `Binding`'ов оказывается в нокдауне, и работает не так, как хотелось бы. Решение — вынести логику разрешения смены таба из сеттера. Заодно и сеттер станет универсально применимым. Ну и UI-логику (message box) можно будет выгрузить из VM, что тоже неплохо.

---

Итак, смотрите, что нужно.

Во-первых, убираем длинные операции из сеттера. Сеттер **должен** быть быстрым.

```
class OuterVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // ...
    private VM _selectedTabVM;
    public VM SelectedTabVM
    {
        get { return _selectedTabVM; }
        set
        {
            if (_selectedTabVM == value) return;
            _selectedTabVM = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedTabVM));
        }
    }
```

Теперь, нам нужно запретить нормальный клик у `TabItem`'а, и перенаправить его на наш код. Для такого нужен какой-нибудь EventTrigger, который бы отменил событие. (Например, как [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23614156/276994).) Но эта техника доставит `EventArgs` в VM, в котором им не место, так что пойдём через attached behavior. (Да, это серьёзное оружие, другого я не нашёл.)

Для начала, подключим через nuget [`System.Windows.Interactivity.WPF`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Windows.Interactivity.WPF/) (References → правая клавиша мыши → Manage NuGet Packages... → Search = `System.Windows.Interactivity.WPF`). Напишем `Behavior`:

```
class RouteClickBehaviour : Behavior<TabItem>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseDown += OnTabItemMouseDown;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseDown -= OnTabItemMouseDown;
        base.OnDetaching();
    }

    void OnTabItemMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        // что делать тут?
    }
}
```

Тут всё просто: при подключении подписываемся на `PreviewMouseDown` у `TabItem`'а, при отключении отписываемся, при приходе клика отмениаем стандартную обработку через `e.Handled`. Почему именно `PreviewMouseDown`? Потому что это событие приходит к нам *до* внутренних обработчиков, и мы можем отменить его, не пустив внутрь.

Теперь встаёт вопрос, а что делать, когда клик задетектирован? Окей, нужно вызвать команду из VM, а уж VM пускай решает, что же делать дальше. Где взять команду и аргумент? Ответ очевиден — прикрепить через attached property. Эти attached property можно было бы положить в отдельный класс, но можно и засунуть в `RouteClickBehaviour`.

Получаем улучшенный вариант:

```
class RouteClickBehaviour : Behavior<TabItem>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseDown += OnTabItemMouseDown;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseDown -= OnTabItemMouseDown;
        base.OnDetaching();
    }

    void OnTabItemMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        var command = GetClickCommand(AssociatedObject);
        var commandParameter = GetClickCommandParameter(AssociatedObject);
        if (command == null)
            return;
        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => command.Execute(commandParameter));
    }

    #region attached property ICommand ClickCommand
    public static ICommand GetClickCommand(DependencyObject obj) =>
        (ICommand)obj.GetValue(ClickCommandProperty);
    public static void SetClickCommand(DependencyObject obj, ICommand value) =>
        obj.SetValue(ClickCommandProperty, value);
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ClickCommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "ClickCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(RouteClickBehaviour));
    #endregion

    #region attached property object ClickCommandParameter
    public static object GetClickCommandParameter(DependencyObject obj) =>
        obj.GetValue(ClickCommandParameterProperty);
    public static void SetClickParameterCommand(DependencyObject obj, object value) =>
        obj.SetValue(ClickCommandParameterProperty, value);
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ClickCommandParameterProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "ClickCommandParameter", typeof(object), typeof(RouteClickBehaviour));
    #endregion
}
```

Единственная тонкость — мы посылаем команду асинхронно.

Следующая проблема, а как добавить attached behavior через стиль в `TabItem`? Создавался бы у нас `TabItem` вручную, проблем бы не было:

```
<TabItem Header="{Binding Header}" Width="100">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <local:RouteClickBehaviour/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

(и команду можно было бы передать через параметры). Но у нас стиль, а с доставкой behavior через стиль [всё сложно](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1647815/276994).

Пойдём стандартным обходным путём: через ещё одно attached property. Дополним `RouteClickBehaviour` вот чем:

```
    #region attached property bool Inject, calls OnInject on change
    public static bool GetInject(DependencyObject obj) =>
        (bool)obj.GetValue(InjectProperty);
    public static void SetInject(DependencyObject obj, bool value) =>
        obj.SetValue(InjectProperty, value);
    public static readonly DependencyProperty InjectProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "Inject", typeof(bool), typeof(RouteClickBehaviour),
            new PropertyMetadata(false, OnInject));
    #endregion

    static void OnInject(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        bool newValue = (bool)e.NewValue;
        var behaviours = Interaction.GetBehaviors(d);
        if (newValue)
        {
            behaviours.Add(new RouteClickBehaviour());
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var b in behaviours.OfType<RouteClickBehaviour>().ToList())
                behaviours.Remove(b);
        }
    }
```

Теперь если установить `Inject = true`, нужный behavior навесится автоматически.

Окей, дальше — нам нужна команда в VM, которая будет решать, сменить Tab или нет. Для команд можно использовать обыкновенную `RelayCommand`. Команду поместим, понятно, туда же, где лежит `modeChangeExecute`:

```
class OuterVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // ...
    public OuterVM()
    {
        ChangeRequested = new RelayCommand(o =>
        {
            if (modeChangeExecute())
                SelectedTabVM = (VM)o;
        });
    }

    public ICommand ChangeRequested { get; }

    bool modeChangeExecute()
    {
        return MessageBox.Show("?", "?", MessageBoxButton.YesNo) == MessageBoxResult.Yes;
    }
```

Окей, и VM-часть готова. Теперь свяжем это всё вместе через XAML.

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding TabItemsVM}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTabVM}"
            TabStripPlacement="Top"> 
            Name="TK">
    <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TabItem">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"/>
            <Setter Property="local:RouteClickBehaviour.Inject" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="local:RouteClickBehaviour.ClickCommand"
                    Value="{Binding DataContext.ChangeRequested, ElementName=TK}"/>
            <Setter Property="local:RouteClickBehaviour.ClickCommandParameter"
                    Value="{Binding}"/>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</TabControl>
```

Устанавливаем `local:RouteClickBehaviour.Inject = True`, чтобы подключился behavior. Команду нужно брать из VM для `TabControl`'а, т. к. решает вопрос переключения именно внешняя VM. В качестве параметра передаём ту локальную VM, которая хочет стать активной.

Проверяем. Должно работать.

Comment: как всегда более чем подробно, спасибо! Буду разбираться и проверять.

Comment: @S.Kost: Пожалуйста!

Comment: Все работает, единственное я заменил `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` на `Application.Current.Dispather`, т.к. вылезала ошибка что `доступ через ссылку на экземпляр невозможен, вместо этого уточните имя его типа`.

Comment: @S.Kost: Странно, у вас правильная версия `System.Windows.Interactivity.WPF`, авторства Microsoft? У меня компилировалось так. (Попробуйте тогда просто `Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(...)`.)

Comment: да, версия 2.0.20525. Попробовал, работает.

Answer (score 1):

А зачем вообще вкладкам свойство `IsSelected` биндить? Ограничьтесь `SelectedItem`, этого будет достаточно. А со свойствами IsSelected контрол тут без вас разберется. А если вам нужно в ВМ знать значение этого свойства, тогда привяжите его через `Mode=OneWay`

**UPD:**

Вот что у меня получилось. Сразу говорю, я не особо заморачивался с архитектурой, просто накидал чтоб быстрее :)

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}">
    <Grid>
        <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTab}">
            <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"/>
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding Content}"/>
                </Style>
            </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

А вот bg

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<Tab> Tabs { get; set; }

    public Tab SelectedTab { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        Tabs = new ObservableCollection<Tab>
        {
            new Tab { Header="Tab1", Content="Tab1 content" },
            new Tab { Header="Tab2", Content="Tab2 content" },
            new Tab { Header="Tab3", Content="Tab3 content" }
        };
        SelectedTab = Tabs[0];
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

public class Tab
{
    public string Header { get; set; }

    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

И у меня все работает отлично, вкладки выделяются по одной. Проблема у вас скорее всего где-то в другом месте, которое вы не показали, думая, что оно не имеет отношения к проблеме. Ищите где у вас присваивается к вкладкам `IsSelected = true`. Или полностью абстрагируйтесь от логики, оставьте только вот эту основу, установив на остальное заглушки и потихоньку подключайте логику.

Comment: IsEnabled здесь не причем) с ним как-раз таки проблем нет

Comment: @S.Kost Таки кстати без понятия, не при чём ли. В том состоянии, что на скрине - у второй вкладки `IsEnabled` не `true` ли случайно?

Comment: @Monk, поправил.

Comment: @S.Kost, обновил ответ

Comment: повторяюсь. `IsEnabled` тут не причем. Я в вопросе написал что свойство `IsSelected` устанавливается в `true` и не снимается.

Comment: @S.Kost, конечно же я перепутал. Не `IsEnabled` а `IsSelected`. Суть не меняется, вы где то накосячили, но нам весь код не видно. Смотрите на пути изменения `IsSelected` в вашем коде, потому что в предложенном мной коде все работает замечательно.