# WPF ComboBox + MVVM, запрос при выборе элемента

Tags: c#, wpf

В процессе работы над проектом возникла необходимость сделать ComboBox  при выборе элемента которого выдавался бы запрос, Вроде - "А Вы уверены?", если нет возвращать старое значение. Вопрос что я делаю не так? FrameWork 4.0. 
Заранее спасибо.

Сейчас у меня получилось следующее:

```
<x:Array x:Key="UnitArray" Type="sys:UInt32" 
   xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
     <sys:UInt32>0x0</sys:UInt32>
     <sys:UInt32>0xFFFFFFFF</sys:UInt32>
</x:Array>

<DataTemplate x:Key="ComboboxOfUnit" >
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">                   
    <TextBlock  VerticalAlignment="Center" >
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="0x0">
                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="value1"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="0xFFFFFFFF">
                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="value2"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

в блоке ресурсов и

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource ResourceKey=UnitArray}" 
      SelectedItem="{Binding UnitOf}" 
      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ComboboxOfUnit}"/>
```

в основном теле xaml кода 
в модели имеем следующее

```
uint _prev_UnitOf;
public uint PrevUnitOf
{
    get { return _prev_UnitOf; }
    set
    {
        _prev_UnitOf = value;

        if (!_prev_UnitOf.Equals(_UnitOf))
        {
           // HasHasChangedArray[_UnitOf_] = true;
            //bfUnitOf = true;
            /HasChanged = true;
        }
        else
        {
            //HasHasChangedArray[_UnitOf_] = false;
            //bfUnitOf = false;
            //HasChanged = isChangedArray();
        }
        OnPropertyChanged(() => PrevUnitOf);
    }
}

uint _UnitOf;
public uint UnitOf
{
    get { return _UnitOf; }
    set
    {

        if (!_UnitOf.Equals(value))
            if (AppContext.Instance.ErrorReportMSG("Вы уверены?", "", Common.Interfaces.MsgType.Question))
            {
                _UnitOf = value;
                if (!_prev_UnitOf.Equals(_UnitOf))
                {

                    //HasHasChangedArray[_UnitOf_] = true;
                    //bfUnitOf = true;
                    //HasChanged = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    //HasHasChangedArray[_UnitOf_] = false;
                    //bfUnitOf = false;
                    //HasChanged = isChangedArray();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                _UnitOf = _prev_UnitOf;
                //bfUnitOf = false;
                //HasChanged = isChangedArray();
            }
        OnPropertyChanged(() => UnitOf);
    }
}
```

где `AppContext.Instance.ErrorReportMSG("Вы уверены?", "", Common.Interfaces.MsgType.Question)` обертка над messagebox 
и OnPropertyChanged(() => UnitOf)

```
public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}

/// <summary>
/// Метод генерации события изменения свойства объекта
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Тип объекта</typeparam>
/// <param name="action">Лямбда функция доступа свойству</param>
protected void OnPropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> action)
{
    var propertyName = GetPropertyName(action);
    OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
}

/// <summary>
/// Метод получения имени параметра
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Тип объекта</typeparam>
/// <param name="action">Лямбда функция доступа свойству</param>
/// <returns>Возвращает имя параметра</returns>
private static string GetPropertyName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> action)
{
    var expression = (MemberExpression)action.Body;
    var propertyName = expression.Member.Name;
    return propertyName;
}
```

Comment: А зачем такие сложности? Ну, вот это `GetPropertyName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> action)` и проч. если вы потом все равно передаете название свойства вот так `OnPropertyChanged(() => UnitOf);`? Тогда уж просто легче передавать название свойства напрямую `OnPropertyChanged("UnitOf");` и не городить огород из expressions. А по сути не понятно в чем проблема? Алгоритм же элементарный, вы в `public uint UnitOf` сверяете `value` с `_UnitOf`, если не равны, выводите окошко, если пользователь хочет изменить, то присваиваете `value` `_UnitOf`, иначе значение `_UnitOf` оставляете прежним.

Comment: К сложностям с GetPropertyName<T> пришёл после проблем с отслеживанием "опечаток" в именах передаваемых в OnPropertyChanged()- проект большой много чего меняется, было что имя поменялось а в  OnPropertyChanged нет. Да так `value = _UnitOf` я не пробовал

Comment: нет значение `UnitOf` не поменялось а текст в Combobox изменился. И при переходе назад зарос на изменение не выдается - `_UnitOf.Equals(value) = true`.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/567880/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%B5-%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B8-tabcontrol-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%83-%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B8

Comment: Для отслеживания опечаток лучше использовать `nameof()` и `CallerMemberNameAttribute` (и не говорите, что у вас .NET 4, это работает и в нем :) )

Comment: вся высоко технологичная часть работает - проверено на других элементах. проблема в том, что  после отказа от изменения и значения текст в комбобоксе отображается изменёны, а а все значения в модели остались со старым значением.

Comment: @Gardes да, интересно надо пробовать, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По-началу вопрос мне показался достаточно простым, однако на практике я столкнулся с той же проблемой: `ComboBox` не хочет "отпрыгивать назад" в случае отмены изменения привязанного свойства `SelectedItem`. Решение нашлось путем гугления и экспериментов, вот [ссылка 1](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/407550/The-Perils-of-Canceling-WPF-ComboBox-Selection) и [ссылка 2](https://nathan.alner.net/2010/04/25/cancelling-selection-change-in-a-bound-wpf-combo-box/). Наиболее полезной оказалась последняя.

Единственный недостаток в таком решении, по моему мнению, в том, что приходится использовать во ViewModel `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()`, т.е. подключать `using System.Windows;` и `using System.Windows.Threading;`, что для ViewModel как бы не комильфо.

Для примера я использовал свойство List со строками, а не как у автора с подключенным ресурсным массивом, но по сути это ничего не меняет.

Такой XAML

```
<Canvas>
    <ComboBox Canvas.Left="30"
              Canvas.Top="40"
              Width="120"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Units}"
              SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedUnit}" />
</Canvas>
```

А вот такая вьюмодель

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly IMainWindow _mainWindow;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    //ctor
    public MainViewModel(IMainWindow mainWindow)
    {
        _mainWindow = mainWindow;
    }

    public List<string> Units { get; set; } = new List<string> { "0x0", "0xFFFFFFFF" };

    private string _SelectedUnit;
    public string SelectedUnit
    {
        get => _SelectedUnit;
        set
        {
            // сохраняем старое значение
            var origValue = _SelectedUnit;

            //меняем значение в обычном порядке
            _SelectedUnit = value;

            //спрашиваем пользователя
            if (!_mainWindow.ShowYesNo("Изменить значение?"))
            {
                // возвращаем предыдущее значение, но только после того как
                // UI закончит свое обновление.
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                        new Action(() =>
                        {
                            _SelectedUnit = origValue;
                            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SelectedUnit)));
                        }),
                        DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle,
                        null
                    );

                //и выходим
                return;
            }

            //Оповещаем как обычно изменение, сделанное до if (!_mainWindow.ShowYesNo("Изменить значение?"))
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SelectedUnit)));

            //а здесь уже преобразуем изменившиеся значение
            //в необходимое uint
            //SetNewUnit(_SelectedUnit);
        }
    }

}
```

Иллюстрация работы

[image: пример работы]