# Как установить Behavior через триггер

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Предположим, у меня есть некий контролл:

```
<TextBox Text="Hello world"
             Margin="5,7">
</TextBox>
```

Нужно поставить ему `Behavior`, если триггер сработает, то есть по факту написать так:

```
<TextBox Text="Hello world"
             Margin="5,7">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
       <Style.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="IsVisible" Value="False">
             <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <behaviors:MyBehavior />
             </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
          </Trigger>
       </Style.Triggers>
     </Style>
</TextBox>
```

Как это можно сделать? И можно ли вообще?

Comment: Можно вывернуть проблему: привязать behavior сразу, подписаться на VIsibleChanged в behavior, а дальше то зачем вам это нужно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно вывернуть проблему: привязать behavior сразу, подписаться на IsVisibleChanged в behavior, а дальше то зачем вам это нужно

```
class MyBehavior : Behavior<TextBox>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.IsVisibleChanged += AssociatedObject_IsVisibleChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        AssociatedObject.IsVisibleChanged -= AssociatedObject_IsVisibleChanged;
    }

    void AssociatedObject_IsVisibleChanged(object sender, System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //TODO: сделать что-нибудь
    }        
}
```

xaml:

```
<TextBox Text="Hello world">    
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <behaviors:MyBehavior/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>         
</TextBox>
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно поступить следующим образом, добавьте в ваш класс поведения такое свойство зависимости:

```
public static bool GetInject(DependencyObject obj)
    => (bool)obj.GetValue(InjectProperty);
public static void SetInject(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    => obj.SetValue(InjectProperty, value);
public static readonly DependencyProperty InjectProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Inject", typeof(bool),
        typeof(MyBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(false, OnInject));

static void OnInject(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    bool newValue = (bool)e.NewValue;
    var behaviours = Interaction.GetBehaviors(d);
    if (newValue)
    {
        behaviours.Add(new MyBehavior());
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (var b in behaviours.OfType<MyBehavior>().ToList())
            behaviours.Remove(b);
    }
}
```

Теперь, если установить `Inject=true`, это поведение применится автоматически. Сделайте это в вашем триггере:

```
<TextBox Text="Hello world" Margin="5,7">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
       <Style.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="IsVisible" Value="False">
             <Setter Property="behaviors:MyBehavior.Inject" Value="True"/>
          </Trigger>
       </Style.Triggers>
     </Style>
</TextBox>
```

Взято из [этого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/571001/218063) @VladD.